# cannot import modules in python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

I use xubuntu 14.04.3,and its default python version is python 2.7.6 and python 3.4.3.Then I download python 2.7.10 source code and compile install with command

```
./configure
make
sudo make -i install
```

`make` shows some modules not found :

```
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers

Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _ssl
_tkinter           bsddb185           bz2
dbm                gdbm               readline
sunaudiodev
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

then I run `sudo pip install pyftpdlib` to install a module,then I can see it installs ok

```
pip show pyftpdlib
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pyftpdlib
Version: 1.4.0
Summary: Very fast asynchronous FTP server library
Home-page: https://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib/
Author: Giampaolo Rodola'
Author-email: g.rodola@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

But when I import pyftpdlib in python shell or .py, python shows error`ImportError: No module named pyftpdlib`
If I modified PYTHONPATH ,I should modified root and normal user, and when using `sudo` ,it's still shows cannot find module.

How to solve this problem? or return to the default states.

Comment: virtualenv will be useful for future package installations

Comment: Did you compile python with openssl support?

Comment: @roymustang86 it's late to use virtualenv. problem has exists.

Comment: @mrnick no. as too many mistake made, I'm trying to return to the original state.

Comment: @roymustang86 And I think this is not package's problem, it should be the conflict between python 2.7.6 and 2.7.10 versions.

Comment: As suggested by mr nick, compile with ssl support. Install libssl-dev or equivalent, then the usual configure;make again and check that you *don't see _ssl in the warning about modules not found.

Comment: I highly recommend Anaconda python. You can install several environments (python 2.7 or 3.4 etc.) alongside of each other without any troubles.

Comment: @Moritz If I install what you recommend ,then my problem will be solved? or I should install it with a clean linux?

Comment: @Evert ssl's problem is solved ,but python and pip are still un-usable

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that Python now works with SSL. And do you still get *exactly* the same error as before?

Comment: I do not know if it will be solved but Anaconda allows you to separate the different python versions in a clean and easy way. So you do not mess your installations up. Or if you do, you can easily switch back to another environment. look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856293/ipython-notebook-python3-not-found-after-uninstalling-anaconda3-for-anaconda/32856439#32856439

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the development libraries for SSL and recompile python.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

You probably also want to `apt-get` `libbz2-dev`, `sqlite3`, `libsqlite3-dev`, and `libreadline-dev`.