# IPython Notebook - python3 not found after uninstalling Anaconda3 for Anaconda

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I uninstalled Anaconda 2.3 with Python 3.4.3 and then installed the same Anaconda version with Python 2.7.10.

When I open a notebook via `$ ipython notebook "Example Notebook.ipynb"` it tries to use the python3 kernel as opposed to opening with the installed python2. Of course I get the error `python3 kernel not found`.

How can I get ipython notebooks to open with the python2 kernel? I've tried to uninstall ipython and ipython notebook, then delete `.ipython` and `.jupyter` from my user directory in case there were any defaults set in these folders, then reinstalled both. Still get the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can install several python versions alongside each other. Just create another environment (replace "all my packages" with the names of the packages).

```
conda create --name mypy_27 python = 2.7
```

or

```
conda create --name mypy_34 python = 3.4
```

afterwards you can activate the environments by typing

```
source activate mypy_34
```

if you then do

```
conda install "all your packages"
```

you install the desired packages in the active environment.

You can do much [more](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html).

Comment: The key is that I currently only have 1 environment which is the root environment for Anaconda 2.3 with Python 2.7.10. Yet the notebook keeps trying to load the non-existent python3 kernel.